# How to descend into a nested array using a list of indexes?

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert a Ruby script into Python that takes an array with indexes as elements (`arr_idx`) and use it to loop through a nested array (`arr`) and returns the value associated with the index (in this example: `['d']`).

In Ruby I'm using the methods `inject` and `fetch` for this:

```
arr = [['a'], [[['b'], [[['c'], ['d']]]]]]
arr_idx = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]

# in Ruby: 
# result = arr_idx.inject(arr) { |a, b| a.fetch(b) } # => ['d']
```

My poor attempt in Python looks like this:

```
result = reduce(lambda a,b: a.get(b), arr, arr_idx)
```

How to convert the Ruby script properly to Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `a[b]` to index a list `a` by `b`. Note that the arguments to `reduce` must be swapped as well:

```py
values = [['a'],[[['b'],[[['c'],['d']]]]]]
indices = [1,0,1,0,1]
result = reduce(lambda current, idx: current[idx], indices, values)
```

This sets the `values` as the `initial` starting point, using it as the first `current` array level. Each step will index the `current` array level by the next `idx` from `indices`.

Comment: This is the correct answer. An equivalent alternative is `reduce(list.__getitem__, indices, values)`, if you want to avoid the lambda syntax. You can also use [`operator.getitem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.getitem) if you import that.

Answer (score 0):

you can try for loop like this:

```
arr = [['a'], [[['b'], [[['c'], ['d']]]]]]
arr_idx = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
tmp = arr

for i in arr_idx:
    tmp = tmp[i]
print(tmp)
```